# Angular2 - children routes on root route with named outlets not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I have the following routing configuration:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'hero-video',
        component: HeroOverlayComponent,
        outlet: 'overlay'
      }
    ]
  }
];

export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES);
```

The idea is that I have one component who has an overlay routing outlet which shows different outlets on that main page. However that does not work, I always get the error that is no such route.

If I remove the outlet part (and of course also update the  selector, everything works.

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'hero-video',
        component: HeroOverlayComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES);
```

Do I miss something or why is the behaviour different if I use a named router outlet or not for root routes?

Comment: How are you navigating to "outlet" route?

Comment: In this case, you should navigate to: `/(outlet:hero-video)`

Comment: yeah, I am using router linke like that: `<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { overlay: ['hero-video'] } }]" queryParamsHandling="preserve">``

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Route configuration looks fine. It seems that Angular has an issue with how you're exporting the router.
I'd suggest changing how you're serving the `RouterModule`.

I'd create `AppRoutingModule` and then import it to main `AppModule` instead of doing it your way.

```
const ROUTES: Route[] = [
  { path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'hero-video',
        component: HeroOverlayComponent,
        outlet: 'overlay'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Then in your `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
   // your imports here
   AppRoutingModule
  ],
  // rest of your configuration here
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you prepare a plunker with your implementation, please?